# Is it possible to create a message loop without creating a window in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-messages, message-loop

I was working with some Bluetooth library and for some Bluetooth callback, it is necessary to use Windows message loop. But as per my requirement, I need to create a normal C++ program without any GUI. Is it possible to create a message loop without a window?

```
main(){
    Discovery disc;
    disc.startDiscovery();
}


Discovery::startDiscovery(){
  __hook(&CallBackFromLibrary::OnDiscoveryStarted, &obj, &Discovery::OnDiscoveryStarted);
  __hook(&CallBackFromLibrary::OnDiscoveryComplete, &obj, &Discovery::OnDiscoveryComplete);  
}


apiObject.discoverBluetoothDevices();
```

In this sample code, I should receive callbacks as OnDiscoveryStarted and OnDiscoveryComplete after calling apiObject.discoverBluetoothDevices().

Since they are using message loops for callbacks, I only got the callback on GUI application. How to receive the callback using message loops as the library documentation says message loops are required.

Comment: I think it's possible. What's your (example, as a [mcve]) code for creating a message loop?

Comment: A message loop is not dependent on a window, but a window is dependent on a message loop. But what kind of messaging is the library using that doesn't involve sending messages to a window? Only 2 possibilities I can think of - thread messages, or an apartment-threaded ActiveX/COM object..

Comment: In all likelihood that Bluetooth library creates a hidden window.  Very common.  So you have to pump a message loop yourself to keep it going, no different from what you'd do if you create a window yourself.

Comment: That or it's designed to work with or without a window, and prefers common code for both use cases (which seems reasonable). I've also written libraries before that use (and, to be fair, also provide) a message loop without necessarily any threading: it makes for some easy interactions between components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message loop in non-GUI thread:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ThreadFunction()
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL result;

    for (;;)
    {
        result = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);

        if (result <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        cout << msg.message << " " << msg.wParam << " " << msg.lParam << endl;

        //TranslateMessage(&msg);
        //DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t(ThreadFunction);
    HANDLE h = t.native_handle();
    DWORD dw = GetThreadId(h);

    PostThreadMessage(dw, WM_APP + 1, 1, 2);
    PostThreadMessage(dw, WM_APP + 2, 10, 20);
    PostThreadMessage(dw, WM_QUIT, 10, 20);

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**:

According to the comment, this code is not compiled in gcc. Trying to reproduce this in VC++, I found that the program doesn't work in x64. This updated solution hopefully solves both problems:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

DWORD threadID{};


void ThreadFunction(HANDLE event_handle)
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL result;

    threadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
    SetEvent(event_handle);

    for (;;)
    {
        result = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);

        if (result <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        cout << msg.message << " " << msg.wParam << " " << msg.lParam << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE e = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);

    thread t(ThreadFunction, e);

    WaitForSingleObject(e, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(e);


    PostThreadMessage(threadID, WM_APP + 1, 1, 2);
    PostThreadMessage(threadID, WM_APP + 2, 10, 20);
    PostThreadMessage(threadID, WM_QUIT, 10, 20);

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get error: `error: invalid conversion from 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'unsigned int'} to 'HANDLE' {aka 'void*'} [-fpermissive]
     HANDLE h = t.native_handle();`

Comment: Cannot reproduce this in VC++ compiler. But I see that this code doesn't work in x64. I will post updated solution later.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out

Comment: There are still race conditions with posted messages being lost before reaching `GetMessage()` func. 
Calling `PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)` once before `SetEvent()` might solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible--Windows will associate a message queue with a thread when/if the thread tries to use one. There is a little bit of a race condition when doing this though. To post to the thread's message queue, you use [`PostThreadMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx). But, the thread won't have a message queue until it calls a function to attempt to read from the message queue (i.e., Windows doesn't create a message queue for the thread until the thread tries to use it).

To prevent a race condition, you usually want to do something on this order:

1. cal CreateEvent to create an event (unsignalled)
2. call `CreateThread`, passing it the handle of the event to be passed to the new thread
3. Have the parent wait for the event
4. have the child call `PeekMessage` (not expecting any result, since the queue hasn't been created yet--but this forces its creation).
5. Have the child signal the event
6. Now the parent will resume, and can use `PostThreadMessage`, secure in the "knowledge" that the child has a message queue, so this will work.

Another possibility is for the child to create a window, but leave it hidden. The obvious advantage here is compatibility with code that expects to post/send messages to a normal message queue using `SendMessage`, `PostMessage`, `SendMessageTimeout`, and so on, instead of the special `PostThreadMessage`. The other obvious advantage is that it avoids the thread-message-queue dance outlined above.

When you get down to it, the primary characteristic of a Windows "window" isn't something on the display--it's a message queue, and what shows up on the display is just drawing that's done in response to some specific messages. A hidden window isn't a whole lot more than a message queue.

Comment: "*To prevent a race condition, you usually want to do something on this order*" - an event object via `CreateEvent()`, or a Condition Variable via `InitializeConditionVariable()` or `std::condition_variable`, would be more appropriate to use than a mutex. You can't signal a mutex.

Comment: How can I hide the window?

Comment: @kittu: `ShowWindow(yourWindow, SW_HIDE)` will hide a window.